# how to get exact run time of r code?

Tags: r

In my code the input taken at run time.if time delay in entering data also showing as my runtime.How to remove user interaction time from code?

Sample code.if i call fun(),readline take value at run time.value of " Answer " entering delay also included in run time.how  remove user entering delay from run time ?

```
fun <- function() {
start.time <- Sys.time()
i<-1
ANSWER <- readline("Are you a satisfied R user? ")
while(i<1000){
sink("D://newdatset.txt")
print(ANSWER)
sink()
i<-i+1}
unlink("D://newdatset.txt")
if (substr(ANSWER, 1, 1) == "n")
cat("This is impossible.  YOU LIED!\n")
else
cat("I knew it.\n")
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <-end.time - start.time 
time.taken
```

}

if i call fun(y).get the correct answer .

```
fun <- function(x) {
start.time <- Sys.time()
i<-1
ANSWER <- "x"
while(i<1000)
{
sink("D://NH.txt")
print(ANSWER)
sink()
i<-i+1}
if (substr(ANSWER, 1, 1) == "n")
cat("This is impossible.  YOU LIED!\n")
else
cat("I knew it.\n")
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <-end.time - start.time 
print( time.taken)}
```

Comment: You can do `system.time(fun)`

Comment: is system.time(fun) call after run fun() ??

Comment: @julinen it showing   user  system elapsed 
              0       0       0                    always

Comment: Its `system.time(fun())` I forget the "()".

Comment: is there any better option ?